# MultiselectList with selected values are not pre selected in View

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a simple service which is :
1. Getting All roles in a system
2. Check the role of current selected user
3. Render all roles in a dropdown , selecting current user roles by default

To do that , I have following code:

```
 public ActionResult Edit(string userId)
        {

            var user = _oAuthUserService.GetUsers()?.Where(u => u.UserId == userId).FirstOrDefault();

            var userRoles = user.Roles; //[Admin,Manager]

            var allRolesFromService = _oAuthUserService.AllRoles.Select(x=>new {
                Id =x.RoleName,
                Name =x.RoleName
            }).ToList(); //All roles in the System [Role1,Role2,Role3,Admin,Manager]


            ViewData["AllRoles"] = new MultiSelectList(allRolesFromService, "Id", "Name", userRoles);


            return View(user);


        }
```

In view I am doing ,

```
@Html.ListBox("AllRoles", (MultiSelectList)ViewData["AllRoles"], new { multiple = "multiple" });
```

But when I navigate to view , none of the items are pre-selected? What am I missing here?

Comment: Try replacing your `ViewData` key name, because `AllRoles` already used to bound with `ListBox`, avoiding potential naming collision. Alternatively use `ListBoxFor` with strongly-typed viewmodel property.

Comment: And changing viewDataKey Works!! Never though it could be the issue, Can you answer the question and I will accept as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs because you're using same `ViewData` key name as model name bound to `ListBox` helper in this line:

```
@Html.ListBox("AllRoles", (MultiSelectList)ViewData["AllRoles"], new { multiple = "multiple" })
```

Assumed that `AllRoles` is an array or list property inside viewmodel class, you can't reuse it as `ViewData` key name because naming collision will happen between them, causing the option lists won't show up properly. You can rename `ViewData` key name with any different name than viewmodel's property name:

```
ViewData["AllRolesList"] = new MultiSelectList(allRolesFromService, "Id", "Name", userRoles);
```

And then use new key name within `ListBox(For)` helper:

**ListBox helper**

```
@Html.ListBox("AllRoles", (MultiSelectList)ViewData["AllRolesList"], new { multiple = "multiple" })
```

**ListBoxFor helper**

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.AllRoles, (MultiSelectList)ViewData["AllRolesList"], new { multiple = "multiple" })
```